# How to delete a line containing two specific keywords in shell?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed, scripting

I have many lines of this format:

```
012343.ux002tesseract!Mat_server5.28746.1.0: Login ****** Oslo      -AXCVT2 - Versio 1.4 13.10.2016
```

Now I want to delete all the lines, which contain both `012343` and `AXCVT2` in it.

As you can see the above line contains both of them.

Comment: I don't see the line containing `012343`. Does the order matter? Ie. can `AXCVT2` be before and after `012343` and both such cases have to be removed?

Comment: yes the order matter .   012343 always comes before AXCVT2 in these lines.

Answer (score 2):

That looks easy with [`sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed), that can be learned from [Sed - An Introduction and Tutorial by Bruce Barnett](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html), which some knowledge of [regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/), which can be easily learned from [regex crosswords](https://regexcrossword.com/):

```
sed '/012343.*AXCVT2/d'
```

Would remove lines containing `012343` followed by anything followed by `AXCVT2`.

To remove lines that contain in both direction, we ex. can do two `sed`s expressions:

```
sed -e '/012343.*AXCVT2/d' -e '/AXCVT2.*012343/d'
```

or shorter:

```
sed '/012343.*AXCVT2/d; /AXCVT2.*012343/d'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/012343/{/AXCVT2/d}' file
```